# `gnulib-tool --update` without altering `.gitignore` files

Tags: gnulib

I am using some gnulib modules on my project. I have chosen to not carry them around in my repository. Every time I do a fresh clone I just run.

```
$ gnulib-tool --update
```

And I am all set up!

One problem though. I have my `.gitignore` files already set up and I am perfectly happy with them. I don't want `gnulib-tool` to mess them up.

Any idea how to get rid of this side effect?

**EDIT: The `--no-vc-files` option doesn't work with `--update`.**

```
$ gnulib-tool --update --no-vc-files
gnulib-tool: invalid options for 'update' mode
Try 'gnulib-tool --help' for more information.
If you really want to modify the gnulib configuration of your project,
you need to use 'gnulib --import' - at your own risk!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the option `--no-vc-files` to the initial `gnulib-tool --import` invocation. gnulib-tool will them remember (through a line in the `gnulib-cache.m4` file) that this option was specified.

You can also hack the `gnulib-cache.m4`: Add the line

```
gl_VC_FILES([false])
```

This will make gnulib-tool think that the option `--no-vc-files` was given when `gnulib-tool --import` was invoked.